# What are the types of inheritances?

Tags: oop

What are the types of inheritances?

1. Multiple
2. Single
3. Multilevel
4. Hierarchical
5. Hybrid

Is that all? Have I missed something from the list?

### EDIT 1

1. Diamond

### EDIT 2

I request all of you to put your comments in answers. I won't be able to select all, but I''l definitely upvote them.

Comment: Multiple appears twice on your list.

Comment: @ripper234 I'm hoping that was intentional!

Comment: @rich.okelly ripper234 sorry, my fault

Comment: @fyr Please put that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general OOP terms, I'm not sure that these translate, but you can have:

- virtual inheritance (might be a pure C++ thing)
- public/protected/private inheritance (these would make sense to be more general terms, and not only apply to C++)